# What are all the different Super Training Ball types?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have noticed that each pokemon has a different type of ball that is "kicked" during super training. This is apparent by the Ball icon to the right of the name of each pokemon. I have seen that different icons mean different kind of skill in super training regimen. I would like to know the different types of "kick powers" that pokemon have and their effects.

Here are a few I have noticed:

1. Three balls - Multishot on full charge
2. Blue Trailblazing ball - Fast Shot on Full charge
3. Green Ball with 'Crown'(Thud) - Heavy score on full charge shots.

I need to confirm these and need to know of the rest that are present in game. Are these powers fixed for every pokemon, or can two pokemon of same species have different super training powers.i.e. My Greninja has the fast blue ball. Can another Greninja have different powers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all, there are 5  different balls you can use. There are Black, Blue, Green, Orange, and Yellow.
This is qouted from:[Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/supertraining.shtml)

> Each Pokémon uses a specific ball at random, based mostly upon the species of Pokemon you are using. These balls have special effects
>
> Black: These balls are average in size, speed and power, but can be shot rapidly
>
> Blue: These balls are incredibly fast with average power. They are small
>
> Green: These balls are incredibly powerful but are slow to fire.
>
> Orange: These balls have an average speed, and are a bit weak. However, they are very large
>
> Yellow: These balls are lower power and have an average speed. They are small, but can be shot rapidly